# how to convert row from csv to ArrayType in Apache spark java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a CSV of 10k rows and I want to find out some pattern. I am referring example for Apache Spark docs. In below example in place of items I am giving list of columns, but getting error.

*The input column must be `ArrayType`, but `StringType`.*

```
FPGrowthModel model = new FPGrowth()
  .setItemsCol("items")
  .setMinSupport(0.5)
  .setMinConfidence(0.6)
  .fit(itemsDF);
```

How to create `ArrayType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
val new_itemsDF = itemsDF.withColumn("items", array(col("items")))
FPGrowthModel model = new FPGrowth()
  .setItemsCol("items")
  .setMinSupport(0.5)
  .setMinConfidence(0.6)
  .fit(new_itemsDF);
```